# ember.js: How to initialize a controller with generateController

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to insert the view & controller from the route `categories` in multiple other routes, without nesting them in that `categories` route (because I want to keep URLs independent).

So, I'm rendering the `categories` template, into the main `application` one, in the outlet `topbar` using the controller I get from my existing `categories` route.

```js
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render();
        this.render('categories', {
            outlet: 'topbar',
            into: 'application',
            controller: this.controllerFor('categories')
        });
    }
});
```

When I visit the `categories` route, all's working fine! I can even browse other routes from there. But if I access first any other route, the `categories` controller seems not to be created:

> Assertion failed: The controller for route 'categories'' could not be found. Make sure that this route exists and has already been entered at least once. If you must intialize the controller without entering a route, use `generateController`.

Nice warning :) I wish all frameworks were that smart! So I'm trying to generate that controller manually... But how?

I tried:

```js
App.CategoriesRoute.create().generateController('categories', App.Category)
```

and the static version:

```js
App.CategoriesRoute.generateController('categories', App.Category)
```

It doesn't seem to be the right way to do. Any help please?

Comment: This behaviour has been introduced with RC7, so it is really new and i have not yet tried myself. Have you tried this.generateController('categories') already?

Comment: did you finally get your controller generated?

Comment: Yes, sorry for late! Works fine now thanks to you guys all :) And just completed @seenivasan's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something inline with our friend **IntuitivePixel.**

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render();

    //assigning the model...
    var context = ['a','b','c','d'];
    var instance = Em.generateController(this.get('container'),'categories',context);
    instance.set('content',context);

    this.render('categories', {
        outlet: 'topbar',
        into: 'application'
    });
  }
});
```

You can do this stuff in model hook itself.

Comment: Check my answer to get the working code. Thanks for your suggestion @seenivasan!

Comment: @MichaMazaheri Thanks for sharing .That seems to very logical.

Answer (score 2):

As @mavilein already mentioned in his comment, this behaviour was recently introduced with the **rc7** release, and lamentably `this.controllerFor('...');` no longer auto generates the corresponding controller for you, so I guess by generating the `CategoriesController` explicitly (in the routes `init` method for example) it should work:

```
App.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.generateController('categories');
});
```

Run the example and check the console: http://jsbin.com/odosoy/62/edit you will see something like this:

```
generated -> controller:categories Object {fullName: "controller:categories"}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To complete answers from **@seenivasan** and **@IntuitivePixel**, here's what I did, and it works perfectly:

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.generateController('categories');
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render();

    //getting the generated controller
    var categoriesController = this.controllerFor('categories');

    //assigning the model
    categoriesController.set('content', App.PostCategory.find());

    this.render('categories', {
        outlet: 'topbar',
        into: 'application',
        controller: categoriesController
    });
  }
});
```

I think it's better to call `generateController` in the `init` function to make sure it's only done once.